# PDO PHP Select while loop not pulling all results

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've created this pdo select and while looping the output:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT memberID,username,power FROM members ORDER BY power DESC";
$stmt = $db->query($sql);
$row = $stmt->fetchObject();
$username = $row->username;
$power = $row->power;
$i = 1;
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo "<li class='list-group-item'><span class='badge'>".$i."</span>". $row["username"] ."</li>". $row["power"] ."";
    $i++;
}
$stmt->closeCursor();
?>
```

The output works as indented however the first row in the database isn't getting output. There are total of 5 rows in the database members. Is there anything above that would be limiting the first result from getting output?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, when you call `fetchObject`, you are already consuming the first row from the result.

Comment: Oh... that makes perfect sense not sure why I had that or the $row-> still in thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT memberID,username,power FROM members ORDER BY power DESC";
$stmt = $db->query($sql);

$i = 1;
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo "<li class='list-group-item'><span class='badge'>".$i."</span>". $row["username"] ."</li>". $row["power"] ."";
    $i++;
}
$stmt->closeCursor();
?>
```

Removed the `fetchObject` and `$row->` to make it output all results. `fetchObject` consumes the first result.